Why is this question unclear?
A few years ago when I was in my first few months of learning Java I asked this question. It got closed for lacking details or clarity.
I would like to know if a question like this could be clarified and if so how because I really think it's a useful question to (curious?) beginners in the language.
Just as a side note: I like the strict moderation model of SO and I think it's what makes this site great and useful and I'm open to even have the meta effect drown the question more if it's really that bad.

The question asks why a language design team has made a decision. Unless a member of that team drops by and tells why, it is pretty unlikely to get anything else than speculations. See also Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?

@BDL Thanks for the link. I benefited especially from Eric Lippert's answer there and have accepted to close this meta question as a duplicate of that one.

Such 'why' questions are better received at the retrocomputing site. Samples: Why is the ‘auto’ storage class specifier included in C?, Why did C have the return type before function names?, and Why was ! chosen for negation?.

cont' - And even Why did XML lose out to XHTML, then HTML 5, on the web?. And Why did MacOS Classic choose the colon as a path separator?.

@PeterMortensen That's nice to know, thanks! I was just discussing this with Karl in the comments of the only answer here.

Because nobody can tell with certainty why certain decisions have been made, except perhaps current or former members of the Java development team.
You could edit the question to fit better with the existing answers that explain the purpose and possibilities of interfaces - although I would personally consider this basic knowledge that can be looked up online and which doesn't warrant a Question on Stack Overflow.

Historically it HAS happened that an actual language designer answered such a question. If there is one place where it can happen, it's on Stack Overflow. It is still not a very useful question, it is merely a bit of trivia.

@Gimby I find the rationale behind language design decisions to be very useful and interesting. I would agree though that it may be not a good fit for SO.

@Gimby I kinda like the idea of a separate SE site for that kind of history question. (I doubt retrocomputing.SE would consider it in scope, but....)

i mean, discussions exists, but good luck getting anyone with knowledge to share to notice it among the rest of the "discussions".

@KarlKnechtel Yeah, me too. I do think it's off topic for retrocomputing and that it's impossible for a proposal like to gain enough traction and participation to succeed as a separate site proposal though unfortunately.
